# Background color for navbar not using my css style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can see many examples on Stackoverflow and online of different methods to change the background color of my bootstrap navigation menu but it is not working and I just don't understand why.

I've tried removing my other CSS items in case they were an issue.  I also tried removing the id from the navigation div.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Basic Front End Portfolio Page</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div id="headertitlebar" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <div id="title" class="navbar-brand">
    <p><a href="#" id="logo">johnsonville.net</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </nav>
  <div id="mainpage">
    <p>
    <h3>I'm a beginner front end developer but an experienced DBA that is working to gather depth as a full stack developer.
  </div>
  </p>
  <div id="portfoliopage">

  </div>

  <div id="contactpage">

  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
  #headertitlebar {
  background-color: firebrick;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#title {
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
#logo {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: black;
}

.nav li {
background: red;
}
```

Comment: You load your style before bootstrap styles meaning it get overriden by bootstrap style. Load bootsrap styles file first then your own after

Comment: @Imphusius I just tried that and it did not make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the css on .navbar-default class.

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

Always works for me.
Hopefully does for you?

I tried your sample and 1 thing is a problem you must use bootstrap's css BEFORE custom css. Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Basic Front End Portfolio Page</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<style>#headertitlebar {
  background-color: firebrick;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
#title {
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
#logo {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div id="headertitlebar" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <div id="title" class="navbar-brand">
    <p><a href="#" id="logo">johnsonville.net</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </nav>
  <div id="mainpage">
    <p>
    <h3>I'm a beginner front end developer but an experienced DBA that is working to gather depth as a full stack developer.
  </div>
  </p>
  <div id="portfoliopage">

  </div>

  <div id="contactpage">

  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Then your css does not get overwritten by bootstrap's.

Then: I edited it for you this ok? New css.

Comment: I"m wanting the menu to be a different color from the other part of the header. I did comment out the background-color from #headertitlebar and used your recommendation and my header is right but the menu color is still not my target color.

Comment: That worked.  I did move it down as you suggested but I think your addition of the correct nesting structure gave me exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.